# Kubernetes - kubectl exec bash - session drop and line width

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I'm having k8s cluster with 3 minions, master and haproxy in front. When I use

```
kubectl exec -p $POD -i -t -- bash -il
```

for accessing bash in the pod (it is a single container in this case) I get in and after something like 5 mins I get dropped out of the terminal. If I reenter the container I can see my old bash process running, with a new started for my new connection. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? When I'm using docker exec it works fine and doesn't drop me so I guess it is from kubernetes.

As a bonus question - is there a way to increase the characters per line when using kubectl exec? I get truncated output that is different from docker exec.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah i am wondering about the line width issue. It makes for really strange text editing as well.

Comment: below mentioned issue has been closed ... if still apparent should be again chased

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known issue - 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/9180

The kubelet webserver times out.

Answer (score 3):

i have resolve by add `env COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES` before bash `kubectl exec -ti busybox env COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES bash`